# C# Naming Suggestion needed

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

```
 public class SomeClass
 {
    private readonly AuthenticationService _authenticationService = null;
    private readonly ProfileService _profileService = null;

    public SomeClass(IAuthenticationService authenticationService, ProfileService profileService)
    {
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
        _bgMeterProfileService = bgMeterProfileService;
    }
   ...
```

Am using _varName for private variable

This is to distinguish between private variable and the constructor parameter.

Wanted to throw this code out in the open to see if there is a better way to distinguish the private variable and method parameters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about `this.variable = variable;`?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx 

The same is suggested above(2.6 Naming).
Marking this as an accepted answere. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are different possibilities.

You could use :

```
this.variable = variable;
this._variable = variable;
this.m_variable = variable;
```

I would personnaly use the first version, and always use "`this.`" when targeting current instance members.

What's most important is that **you always use the same convention** everywhere in your code.

Comment: +1 for this.VarName usage. Aligned with the official framework design guideline

Answer (score 1):

I've been using `_varName = varName;`-convention for last several years and will continue using it for next several ones at lease as most convenient in terms of mostly discoverability(intellisense), debugging/readability(to avoid ambiguity with local vars).

Answer (score 0):

it's important to provide distinction between private and public items.

Some people use a leading underscore and some people use hungarian notation e.g. m_intMyIntVar or m_strMyStringVar

where m_ denotes a member and the next bit is the type abbreviation then a name.

Mostly it's down to personal preference.